# I can't decode encoded text using python

Tags: python, decode

```
from base64 import b64decode
uio = input("Please enter the text you want to decode...")
pu = b64decode(uio.decode()) 
print("Decode text : ")
print(pu)
```

It tells me this : -

```
pu = b64decode(uio.decode())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: A simple look at the python docs would have made this question unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to `decode()` a string object. That does not work.
simply remove that and it should not raise an error anymore, like so:

```
pu = b64decode(uio)
```

If you're not certain there's always a string object do this:

```
try:
   pu =  b64decode(uio.decode('utf-8'))
except AttributeError:
   pu = b64decode(uio)
```

If you're keen on performance, note that `try/except` statements are preferred if the statement in `try` more often than not succeeds. If it doesn't, either replace it using an `if/else` statement, or simply swap the statements in `try/except` - but make sure it's catching a specific exception.

Also note that in python3, `b64decode()` takes a `byte-like` object, instead of a string. Hence, the above code would have to be this instead:

```
try:
    pu = b64decode(uio.encode('utf-8'))  # Note the use of encode()
except AttributeError:
    pu = b64decode(uio)
```

Comment: That is, of course, assuming your input for `b64decode()` is valid.

Answer (score -1):

In Python 3, all strings are unicode. Thus, decode is not necessary. (Also, you are supposed to specify an encoding anyways :) ). Example:

```
pu = b64decode(uio.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It will raise an error, since input needs to be a byte-like object, not a string.